# Help setting up USB joystick for Far cry 3 on PC

Tags: pc, controllers, far-cry-3

I am trying to set up my USB joystick to work with my Far cry 3 on my PC. But its not detected. One of my friend suggested that i should use [x360ce](https://code.google.com/p/x360ce) to emulate the xbox controller to work in my PC.

I have followed every instruction specified in the site. The `x360ce.exe` does recognize my joystick. But the game doesnt.

I changed `xinput.dll` from 1_1 to 4_1. But nothing seems to work in far cry.

Has anyone successfully emulated the gamepad for far cry 3 in PC.?  any help much appreciated

Comment: Could you add the name of the joystick you are using or perhaps a link to the product page for it?  Knowing more about the stick might help us answer the question.

Comment: Sure @MadMAxJr, its Logitech Gamepad F310. you can find the details here http://gaming.logitech.com/en-in/product/f310-gamepad

Answer (score 2):

I have tried all possibilities with x360ce. Nothing seems to work. Finally i mapped keyboard keys to pad using [joy2key](http://www.electracode.com/4/joy2key/JoyToKey%20English%20Version.htm). Now everything works fine

Comment: The gamepad you listed should natively support this.  The only thing I can think of is checking the switch on the bottom side of the gamepad to make sure it's set for Xbox 360 emulation.  Sounds like you found a viable solution though!

Answer (score -1):

[Motioninjoy](http://www.motioninjoy.com/) is a tool that lets you use a PS3 controller on a PC, but it can also be used for other controllers like the Dualshock 3, Sixaxis and your xbox controller.

This is a guide on [Gamefront](http://www.gamefront.com/how-to-use-a-ps3-controller-on-a-pc/) with instruction on how to use it.